# Maximum electric field in a circle

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, coulombs-law

I have a question as follows:

"Show that $E_x $ on the axis of a ring charge of radius $a$ has its maximum value at $x = \pm a /\sqrt{2} $. Sketch $E_x$ versus x for both positivve and negative values of $x$"

This is a bit more abstract than my other questions "Given some givens, find the electric field at this point". As I understand I need to find a function $E_x (x)$ along all x from $-a$ to $a$, and confirm the maxes by taking its derivative that $E_x '(x) = 0$ at the given maxes.

I take a point on $x$ axis, I call it $x$. Considering all $dQ$ along the circle, all of the electric field should be along the x axis due to symmetry. That's nice I guess. The line towards $dQ$ forms an unknown length I'll call $w$. The line projected down from this point on $dQ$ I'll call $u$, and the point from the end of the projection back to $x$ is $v$. I don't have the rep to draw a pretty picture and share it here unfortunately.

The direction I'm obviously going is some trigonometry trickery, but I have no idea where to go. I have $u,v,w$ as triangle sides and are unknowns and $w$ is needed for the distance part of the coulumb's equation. there is the triangle with $a,x,w$ but isn't a right triangle and I'm unsure of any useful properties to work with there. Perhaps there's some actual physics I have overlooked. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're very much on the right track, well done.

You won't need too much trickery: try thinking in terms of electrostatic potentials rather than fields. Then any point on the $x$ axis is equidistant from all points on the ring; this constant distance, by Pythagoras's theorem is simply $\sqrt{x^2 + a^2}$. So your electrostatic potential as a function of $x$ for a point on the axis is:

$$V(x) = -\frac{Q}{4\,\pi\,\epsilon_0} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2 + a^2}}$$

where $Q$ is the total charge Now differentiate once wrt to $x$ to find $E_x$ (recall $\mathbf{E} = - \nabla V$) and then maximize this latter expression for the electric field.

If you must use electric field rather than potential, then the $x$-component from the charge is $|\mathbf{E}|^2 \cos\theta$ where $\theta$ is the angle between the line joining the charge and the point on the $x$-axis in question and the $x$-axis itself. So you use the inverse square law to find $|\mathbf{E}|$ and then $\cos\theta = \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2 + a^2}}$.

I'm sure you find arguments like those often given in class "by symmetry" without further explanation annoying, because, as you say, you're then "guessing" or using ones "intuition": I certainly did. Here's a way to tighten such an argument and make it more precise so that hopefully you find it a bit more satisfying: there are many isometric transformations that we could do on this system and still leave it the same relative to any particular Cartesian co-ordinate system: rotation through any angle about the $x$ axis, rotation through a half turn about the $y$ axis, rotation through half a turn about the $z$ axis. So, you conclude, the system's behavior **must** be the same even after any sequence of these transformations are imparted to it. So, to argue rigorously, you assume that there is a $E_y$ or $E_z$ component along the $x$-axis and impart the $z$ and $y$ rotations to see what happens to the system's description. You can soon prove that there can be no $E_y$ or $E_z$ because then the system's description would otherwise change after these half turns are imparted to it.

Comment: I've actually never seen electrostatic potential before. Class has only been for a week. As a result none of your circle distance at all x being the same voodoo makes much sense :)

Comment: @user193138 see my mods, I've made comments on how to do it without potentials.

Comment: @user193138 and you'll also have to sketch the geometry. I mean that: take any constant point P on the x axis: then  any point on the ring is the same distance from P as any other point. If you sketch the geometry in the $x-z$ plane, say, so that the sketch plane contains the $x$ axis, then the ring intersects the plane at $(0,0,\pm a)$ and if P has an x-coordinate of x, then the distance from P to the ring is $\sqrt{x^2 + a^2}$ and this result does not depend on the plane as long as the plane contains the x-axis.

Comment: @rod [link](http://imgur.com/AZxeIp4) heres a point on x with pink lines connected to 2 different spots on circle with radius a for reference. i have no idea how the distance from point p on x axis to any point on the ring as the same, nor how it collapses to sqrt(x^2 + a^2). if this is something trivial then explain it like im a baby at this point.

Comment: @user193138 I see your problem. Are you sure the $x$ axis is the one you've drawn? I was assuming it was *normal* to the plane of the ring - this would make more sense as an elementary problem, since the problem you have drawn has divergent fields at the rings. Moreover, the x-axis normal to the ring does give the right answer for the maximum fields: these maximums are at $x = \pm a /\sqrt{2} $.

Comment: @rod How unfortunate for me, I'll fiddle with it on the bus with that position.

Comment: @user193138 I think you really need to check what is being asked. If you do the problem shown on your link, you'll need elliptic integrals to describe the field, the field becomes infinite at the ring and there are NO maximums in the field (aside from the infinite divergences) - certainly none at $x = \pm a/\sqrt{2}$. Such a thorny problem would teach very little about electrostatics and be unsolvable for students in a first course, so either your lecturer is slightly insane or you've misread the problem. The problem I assumed would be a much more instructive one for elementary electrostatics.

Comment: @rod Yeah, that's what I meant by that. I solved in up in a few minutes with the proper setup. Thanks.